# nvim [syntax highlighting]

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

I'm using `macOS` with the `kitty terminal emulator`.
The problem I have is when working with `.tex` files:

The syntax highlighting of `nvim` is overlapping to colors so I have to mark those spots in order to be able to read them
(see below in line 1)
How can I change that?
Changing the theme doesn't help either

[image]

Comment: Welcome to vi.SX @hal3m Well, your screeshot shows weird thing. What colortheme are you using? Also try to play with `:set bg=light` and `:set bg=dark` to see which one is better; maybe Vim is failing to determine correctly you terminal.

Comment: @gildux: thanks for your response!
right now it's neapolitan ( i just tried using another one to see the difference)
alas, it's not about the background either ( tried also)
it must be the syntax highlight that vim applies to latex documents but idk how to solve this ... 
so in those blank spots the background is identical to the font color ...

Comment: The only mention I was able to found about it is [here](https://github.com/webdesserts/velvet) and it's not using portable colours but high definition maps for GUI... Really try something like `:se colo koehler` to see if you got a more readable thing.

Comment: that works. played around a bit, it's ok now

Comment: Great :) Please write an answer on the true diagnostic and who you solve it, so it can help people who come later with the same issue.

Comment: hm, but it's more like slapstick,
I just tried out a couple of fonts in my terminal and then at the same time wrote a font into my vim config. So they interact in a weird way. I don't even know the process :)

I guess one obvious way would be to make vim inherit the terminal font. Too lazy to try now